# what is skewed column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I found some bottleneck of my query which select data from only single table then require time and 
 i used non unique key index on two column and with column used in where clause.

`select name ,isComplete from Student where year='2015' and isComplete='F'`

Now i found some concept from internet like skewed column so what is it? 
have an idea then plz help me?
and how to resolve problem of skewed  column?
and how skewed column affect performance of the Query?

Comment: What columns is the index on, in what order?

Comment: @GriffeyDog  , see below physical table like Student (StudID,Name,year,isComplete,location) and index is on year and isComplete

Answer (score 4):

Skewed columns are columns in which the data is not evenly distributed among the rows.

For example, suppose:

- You have a table `order_lines` with 100,000,000 rows
- The table has a column named `customer_id`
- You have 1,000,000 distinct customers
- Some (very large) customers can have hundreds of thousands or millions of order lines.

In the above example, the data in `order_lines.customer_id` is skewed.  On average, you'd expect each distinct `customer_id` to have 100 order lines (100 million rows divided by 1 million distinct customers).  But some large customers have many, many more than 100 order lines.

This hurts performance because Oracle bases its execution plan on statistics.  So, statistically speaking, Oracle thinks it can access `order_lines` based on a non-unique index on `customer_id` and get only 100 records back, which it might then join to another table or whatever using a `NESTED LOOP` operation.

But, then when it actually gets 1,000,000 order lines for a particular customer, the index access and nested loop join are hideously slow.  It would have been far better for Oracle to do a full table scan and hash join to the other table.

So, when there is skewed data, the optimal access plan depends on which particular customer you are selecting!

Oracle lets you avoid this problem by optionally gathering "histograms" on columns, so Oracle knows which values have lots of rows and which have only a few.  That gives the Oracle optimizer the information it needs to generate the best plan in most cases.

Comment: So what is an alternative solution to do always analyse table or change sql query?

Comment: Best is to gather table statistics with histograms.  An on-the-fly alternative might be to use the `/*+ DYNAMIC_SAMPLING(4) */ hint.

Comment: Also, Oracle 12c has adaptive query plans.  There, Oracle is a little smarter.  Theoretically, if it encountered one of these big customers with a million order lines, it would realize halfway through that continuing with a NESTED LOOP join is going to be bad.  It will silently switch halfway to a FTS with a HASH JOIN.  I don't have a lot of practical experience yet regarding how well that works.

Answer (score -1):

Full table scan and Index Scan both are depend on the Skewed column.
and Skewed column is nothing but your spread like gender column contain 60 male and 40 female.